# nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get this Python error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
FINISHED
```

When I try to create the bulkoader.yaml file for a Google App Engine datastore on Mac Os Mavericks, Python 2.7

Answer (score 7):

Are you on a VPN by chance.   There is an issue on MacOS with several VPN clients that can cause this error.   Especially if it is trying to determine your local machines name.   It goes way for me if I sign off of my work VPN, or add the machines host name to the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: I have the same issue. When I'm connected to VPN via Pritunl, I see this error. I have to disconnect from VPN for it to work. Anybody found a workaround?

Comment: Need the VPN to be set to split tunnel.