# socket.gethostbyname fails on macOS

Tags: python, sockets

Does anyone know why the following command gives an error on macOS:

```
import socket    
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

With the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

System:
macOS Big Sur (version 11.2)
Python: Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 07:03:16)

In a Windows system, it works fine and returns an IPv4 address.

I also turned off VPN as pointed out in the following post:
[nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812752/nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known)

Comment: *"I tried Dask's example with localhost, ..."* - you seem to assume some specific context which the reader unfortunately does not share with you. Without such context the question can not be understood and answered, with such context maybe.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is the same. I assume some people at some point had it.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of several questions for me, see [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=socket.gethostname%28%29+macos+site%3Astackoverflow.com) or as one example [Simple Python socket server does not run on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767306/simple-python-socket-server-does-not-run-on-macos).

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the **Answer for your Apple question** forum.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253834/439511

In summary:

We need to add the IP address and hostname into the /etc/hosts file.
First, get the hostname and copy it to the clipboard (this will be your_hostname)

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

Then open */etc/hosts* file (`sudo vi /etc/hosts`) and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1  your_hostname
```

Reopen the terminal. This resolved my issue.

Update: @BrianC also mentioned this in their response, somehow I missed it at the first glance. See the response here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409894/6246352

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. import ipaddress and socket

```
    ip4 = str(ipaddress.ip_address(8888))
    return socket.gethostbyname(ip4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).